# Drupal 7 used s3fs modules to storage images, now how to use aws cloudfront CDN for my website?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

My website is built using Drupal 7 and uses **s3fs** modules for storing all files and images, I use **i18n** to translate my website from source language English to french, german, and more. I use domain as multi domain was working well

I want to use the CDN module to speed my website, so I try to use AWS CloudFront service for it. However, I am confused as to how to do it.
Because the s3fs module makes images use aws s3 store to server images files, and how to use aws CloudFront to server all websites files through CDN?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CloudFront distribution for your S3 bucket, that's going to be unrelated of how you upload your files in the S3 bucket itself.

After that you can install the CDN module, to use the distribution of your S3.

[From this tutorial of AWS:](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/accelerating-your-drupal-content-with-amazon-cloudfront/)

> There is one module, not included in the Core Package that I would
>   consider. This is the CDN Module, produced by Wim Leers. It has been
>   actively developed since its initial release in 2008 and has been
>   re-written for Drupal 8. This module changes file URLs so that CSS,
>   JavaScript, images, audio, and videos can be cached within CloudFront
>   more easily. It also changes the URL when a file is changed by a user
>   in Drupal. This allows the content to be cached early, without having
>   to think about expiring content from the cache. To enable the module,
>   go your Drupal Administration site, and click the Extend Tab. From
>   there, click the blue button for “+ install new module.” I looked up
>   the latest version supporting Drupal 8, and provided the URL to the
>   .tar.gz file. In my case, this was
>   https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/cdn-8.x-3.2.tar.gz.

Also remember that you would [need to invalidate the cache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) if you change the underlying content of a file in S3. Eg. update a file content but the filename is the same.